# Generic Higher kinded types

Tags: scala, types, existential-type, higher-kinded-types

```
class Toto[F[_]]()
val totos: Seq[Toto[_]] = Seq(new Toto[Future[_]], new Toto[IO[_]])
<console>:12: error: _$1 takes no type parameters, expected: one
       val totos: Seq[Toto[_]] = ???
                           ^
```

How do we use wildcard for higher kinded types?
I just want a `Seq` or `Toto` no matter what `F` is.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change `Toto` to be covariant, the following might work:

```
import language.higherKinds

class Toto[+F[_]]()

class Foo[X]
class Bar[X]

val toto: Toto[F] forSome { type F[X] } = new Toto[Foo]
val totos = Seq[Toto[F] forSome { type F[X] }](new Toto[Foo], new Toto[Bar])
```

Feels similar to [this one](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8039).

If this happens more often in your code, you might also consider just moving `F` out of your way by converting it into a type member of `Toto`:

```
import language.higherKinds

class Toto {
  type F[X]
}

object Toto {
  def empty[A[X]]: Toto = new Toto {
    type F[X] = A[X]
  }
}

class Foo[X]
class Bar[X]

val totos: Seq[Toto] = Seq(Toto.empty[Foo], Toto.empty[Bar])
```